# iPhone calendar: How do you set up an event for next year?

Tags: iphone, applications, calendar

I want to set up a reminder for 1 Aug 2021, but there's no way to set the year. All I can do on the scrolling wheel of dates is set it up for this 1 Aug 2020 and add a "repeat annually" to the entry.

Surely Apple haven't missed this off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Calendar switch on All-Day, then you can chose the year easily. 
In Reminder the year switch is shown by default. 
[image: calender all day]

Comment: Excellent! Works a treat. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the spinner forwards.  Go past the end of this year and you'll be in next year.

Or, go to the date in the calendar first before adding the appointment.

Comment: That's a lot of spinning to go from Feb 2020 to Aug 2021!